# If I create a Scheduled Reminder for Event feedback, eg 16 hours after, should I expect it to go out to all past events?

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

We set up a Scheduled Reminder with a link to a webform for event feedback. It is set to go out 16 hours after the event.

We did not expect it to go out to all past events (hundreds of events with thousands of participants over many years)

A/ is this a bug that can/should be fixed

B/ should there be a warning when setting up Scheduled Reminders that these may go out to a much wider audience than expected

C/ is there some way we could have worked around this if we had known it was likely?

Comment: Hey Pete, my understanding was always that there was a window within which scheduled reminders worked and my assumption had been it was 24hrs. I remember seeing it in code somewhere. I wouldn't have expected all past event to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is a core bug and Fuzion are working on a fix for this [JIRA issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20480)

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue - making a new post-event feedback email live via Scheduled Reminders unexpectedly triggered emails to hundreds of past attendees of events from years ago.

Until the issue is fixed, one workaround is to set-up a Smart Group that adds attendees to new events of this type that occur only after a certain date. Then in Scheduled Reminders, use the "Limit to" field to only send out to contacts in this Smart Group.